# An optimization question on the unit sphere

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization

Let $ \Bbb S^{d-1}=\{(x_1,\cdots ,x_d): x_1^2+ \cdots +x_d^2=1\}\subset \Bbb R^d$ be the unit
sphere. Let $\nabla u= (\partial_{x_1}u,\cdots, \partial_{x_d}u)$ be the gradient of a function $u\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ with $\Omega \subset \Bbb R^d$ open. For $e\in \Bbb S^{d-1}$, we write $$\nabla u(x)\cdot e = \partial_{x_1}u(x) e_1+\cdots+\partial_{x_d}u(x) e_d.$$

Then, for $p\geq 1$, what is the following quantity?

\begin{split}
I(u) =\sup_{e\in \mathbb{S}^{d-1}}\int_\Omega |\nabla u(x)\cdot e|^pdx 
\end{split}

I have tried to use the fact that for all $z\in \Bbb R^d$ we have, $$|z|=\sup_{e\in \mathbb{S}^{d-1}}|z\cdot e|$$ And only got the upper estimate $$I(u)\leq \int_\Omega |\nabla u(x)|^pdx$$

Comment: I think it's possible that if $p > (n-1)/(n-2)$, then $I(u) \le c\|u\|_p^p$. By writing $I(u)$ using $(L^p)^* = L^{p'}$ as $I(u)^{1/p} = \sup |\int (\nabla u\cdot e)g\,dx| = \sup|\int u(\nabla g\cdot e)\,dx|$, and then Hölder, get $I(u)^{1/p} \le \|u\|_p\|\nabla g\|_{p'}$. Then I think if $n-1>p'$, or equivalently $p > (n-1)/(n-2)$, we have $\|\nabla g\|_{p'}\le c\|g\|_{p'} \le c$. (The sup is over all $g\in L^{p'}$ with $\|g\|_{p'}\le 1$.) I couldn't find a proof that $\|\nabla g\|_{p'}\le c\|g\|_{p'} \le c$ if $n-1>p'$, and I found this condition using characteristic functions.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Since $|e|=1$, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality entails $|\nabla u\cdot e|\leq |\nabla u| $. So that inequality is right.